# How to create a path object in FXML?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

In javafx2 I am trying to create a  object in fxml.  I want to then be able to reference it from the controller?

```
<BorderPane>
            <center>
                <Path id="ad"/>
            </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Is not working? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Whoops needed to import Path in the fxml file.

```
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Path?>
```

Comment: As you solved a problem yourself, please, `accept` your own answer to follow the site guidelines. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it for details.

Answer (score 1):

Also need to add an fx:id in the opening markup. e.g.:

```
<BorderPane>
            <center>
                <Path id="ad" fx:id="ad1"/>
            </center>
</BorderPane>
```